# Can I target netstandard1.6 using NETStandard.Library 1.5.0-rc2-24027?

Tags: .net-core

My library project targets `netstandard1.6` and takes a dependency on `NETStandard.Library 1.5.0-rc2-24027`. The project compiles.

I have a console application project that references the library project. The console application targets `netcoreapp1.0` and takes a dependency on `Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.0-rc2-3002702` (a 'platform' dependency). This project does not build:

> Project is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Project supports: netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6).
>
> One or more projects are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.

Without the reference to the library project, a build of the console application project succeeds.

Is the problem here that the NETStandard.Library 1.5.0-rc2-24027 package does not yet target netstandard1.6? (See [package information on NuGet.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library/1.5.0-rc2-24027).)

Comment: These profile names are a giant mess, the Microsoft programmers that work on the project every day [no longer know what they mean](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3378).  "it's not an alias, it's a different thing" is about as good as it gets.  Tends to happen when you have a look in the kitchen long before dinner is ready to be served.  You'll surely have to get ahead by having these projects use the same profile.

Comment: They introduced Version 1.6 only a few days ago: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/commit/9c5f892e3ac822fff959cba6d989dceb518e52c9. It's not in the rc2 branch, but in the rtm one. Thus, I would go with 1.5 until rtm. Maybe the package Version 1.5.0-rc2-* correlates somehow with the max. .NET Standard Version, but that would not explain why the library compiles...

Comment: @AxelHeer The link to the GitHub commit returns a 404

Comment: @MichielvanOosterhout https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/commit/9c5f892e3ac822fff959cba6d989dceb518e52c9

Comment: I am not really sure what these versions means anymore.

Answer (score 4):

It seems one of your projects targets netcoreapp1.0 but not all of the referenced projects do. I've had a similar problem.
I was targeting framework netcoreapp1.0 but a reference I was using only supported netstandard1.6.

For me the solution was to import netstandard1.6 in my netcoreapp1.0 target:

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
         "dependencies": {
             "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
               "type": "platform",
               "version": "1.0.0"
             }
          },
          "imports": [
              "netstandard1.6"
          ]
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When writing a library, you should target the lowest `netstandard` that still has all the dependencies that you need.

Since you're using the RC2 version of `NETStandard.Library`, and `netstandard1.6` was only introduced after RC2, to me that indicates that you should use `netstandard1.5` or maybe even a lower version than that.

If you really want to use `netstandard1.6`, you will need to use post-RC2 `dotnet` CLI, links to that are [in README of the dotnet/cli repo](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/#installers-and-binaries).

Comment: If I change the target framework to `netstandard1.5` or even `netstandard1.0` then `dotnet build` exits with "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." 

I installed 1.0.0-preview2-003041 of .NET Core CLI (replacing 1.0.0-preview1-002702) but unfortunately that didn't fix the bug.

Comment: If you change the target framework, you need to re-run `dotnet restore` before `dotnet build`. Error messages for that kind of situations are not great yet.